# Learning .NET with mono

Tags: .net, mono

I saw some very neat code snippets of programs implemented with .net technologies, such as asp.net and c#, and I would like to try out the .net framework.

Now: my development machine runs GNU/linux; my setup (window manager, vim scripts, keyboard shortcuts, default workspaces etc.), continuously improved in the last four years, is something I could never renounce to - the sole thought of using the mouse again when developing makes my wrist hurt) so I was thinking, before investing ~one week to reproduce it on windows (btw, it doesn't look like there's a lot of valuable tiling WMs out there), to try it out on mono.

**Question:**

Which technologies/languages work best on mono? Which don't? Do I really miss something without using microsoft's own IDEs?

I read the monodevelop's about page, but I wouldn't mind real-life experiences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mono pretty much replicates all non-windows-specific parts of the .NET framework.

Most of the work has been around C#, but there are working VB.NET and F# compilers.

There are working libraries for windows forms, though GTK# is better supported and more widely used (within the mono community).

As for visual studio - it is the best IDE out there, better than monodevelop and anything else I have seen. Integrated debugging, editing, intellisense, building and more. To be honest, this is mostly a matter of opinion - you need to try for yourself and decide.

Comment: As for visual studio: does it have a shortcut system so that I will never, for any reason short of a zombie attack, take my hands off the keyboard?

Comment: @cbrandolino - It does, and it is very customizable. I believe there are vi and emacs keyboard bindings floating around, it that's how you run ;) See this page and the links from it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576362.aspx

Comment: @Oded, thanks - I will definitely try Visual Studio under wine, then, and maybe endure the challenge of making a windows machine development-friendly ^^

Comment: @cbrandolino - Though Visual Studio is one of the top supported apps for wine, virtual machines are your friend.

Comment: @Oded, I know, but when I use VirtualBox in single window mode my wm key bindings get picky.

Comment: @cbrandolino - Fair enough... I never used VirtualBox... I am a VMWare man ;)

Comment: well, not a lot of time passed but I guess I have all I need for my decision, so.

Comment: I do suggest you *try* MonoDevelop too - there are quite a few people who like it better than VS. You should be able to load the same projects in either IDE.

Comment: I agree that learning dotnet with microsofts visual studio is much easier than with monodevelop or sharpdevelop. Using one of the free express editions (-c# or web-developper edition) does the job nearly as good as the non-free editions. would be intresting to see how good this works with wine. According to [Wine DB-VSExpress2005](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=14208) and [Wine DB-VSExpress2005](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=11210) the ides do not run with wine 1.2-but this may have changed with newer versions.